# I have trouble to connect vue2-editor (a rich text editor) to my Vue.js blog app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, components, rich-text-editor

I have trouble connecting vue2-editor to my VueJs blog app. I did npm to install it and followed implementation instructions from docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-editor

This is how I am doing it:

In **main.js** file

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor"; // Vue Editor

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

let app;
const auth = getAuth();

onAuthStateChanged(auth, () => {
    if(!app) {
        createApp(App)
        .use(store)
        .use(router)
        .use(VueEditor) // Vue Editor
        .mount('#app')
    }
})
```

In **CreatePost.vue** Component

```js
<template>
  <div class="create-post">

          <!-- vue editor container -->
          <div class="editor">
            <!-- vue editor -->
            <vue-editor :editorOptions="editorSettings"/>
          </div>

          <div class="blog-actions">
              <button>Publish Blog</button>
              <router-link class="router-button" to="#">Post Preview</router-link>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "CreatePost",
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {
            error: null,
            errorMsg: null,
            editorSettings: {
                modules: {
                    imageResize: {},
                },
            },
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

but the Editor don't show in browser instead I got an error in console saying:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: vue-editor
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <CreatePost onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

here is the screenshot from console:

[image: error I got in console saying: Failed to resolve component: vue-editor If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.]

I have even avoided to import vue2-editor from **main.js** and import it locally in the component

In **CreatePost.vue** Component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="create-post">

          <!-- vue editor container -->
          <div class="editor">
            <!-- vue editor -->
            <vue-editor :editorOptions="editorSettings"/>
          </div>

          <div class="blog-actions">
              <button>Publish Blog</button>
              <router-link class="router-button" to="#">Post Preview</router-link>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor"; // import Vue Editor in Create Post component

export default {
    name: "CreatePost",
    components: { VueEditor },
    data() {
        return {
            error: null,
            errorMsg: null,
            editorSettings: {
                modules: {
                    imageResize: {},
                },
            },
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

then remove VueEditor import in **main.js** file like so

In **main.js** file

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

let app;
const auth = getAuth();

onAuthStateChanged(auth, () => {
    if(!app) {
        createApp(App)
        .use(store)
        .use(router)
        .mount('#app')
    }
})
```

And sadly I got different error below

[image: second error when I modify the code]

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: no i didn't find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Hey issue with the vue version, it supports only 2.x.x version of vue. Try with vue 2.x.x

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).